# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returning always nil

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get date from a string having this format :

```
dateString = @"2014-10-15T00:00:00.000Z"
```

I've tried many kinds of NSDateFormatter format such as : @"yyyy-MM-dd" or "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS" but I'm having always nil into my NSDate Variable.

suggestions ?

Best regards

Comment: Use `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` Format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below format `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *dd = [df dateFromString:@"2014-10-15T00:00:00.000Z"];
NSLog(@"%@",dd);
```

and i got below output.

> 2014-10-15 00:00:00 +0000

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: I'm sure this question is a duplicate, aren't you?  In fact I'd stake my life on it.

Comment: Thanks, It's working :) Is there a way to have something like 2014-10-15 in my date variable with the same kind of input string ?

Comment: you can convert dateTostring using GMT TimeZone format.`[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];` and `[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd]` .